# How to check in if my file has executable bit permission set in repo

Tags: git

Below is the command I tried below to set executable permission and push my code in my local repo:

```
ls -l post.py

-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxxx xxxxx     2 Dec 24 00:04 post.py

git add post.py
git commit -am "Commit Change"
..............................
create mode 100644 post.py

git update-index --chmod=+x post.py
git commit -am "update file permission"

git push
```

Are the steps correct - cause in my snapshot I do not see the file permission as 755 but still 644?

After my push to my repo I re-cloned it in a separate location and saw that the file post.py is still having file permissions set as 644 (-rw-r--r--) and not 755(-rwxr-xr-x)?

Cause when only after the executable bit is set on OS file level can I execcute my script:

```
./post.dy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all set git to track `chmod` changes

```
git config core.filemode true
```

Now do what you did again:

```
git update-index --chmod=+x post.py
```

commit the changes

```
git commit -m "update file permission"
[master 77b171e] Changing file permissions
0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
mode change 100644 => 100755 post.py
```

And verify that you can see the `chmod` changes now.